# meteor check user role from client side

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to check the role of the current user and return a specific section of the page.

I have tried the below but not working:

```
if (Roles.getUsersInRole("admin")) {
return (....)
   } else {
return (...)
}
```

And

```
if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(),"admin")) {
    return (....)
       } else {
    return (...)
    }
```

I already have my subscription and publication working below:

Publication:

```
if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, "admin")) {
      return Meteor.users.find({});
    } else {
      return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId });
    }
```

Subscripton

```
Meteor.subscribe("users");
```

Is there a way that I can check the user role from the client side and dynamically present sections of pages?

Comment: What behavior weere you expecting and what did you get?

Comment: I was expecting the only the admin user to view the section of the page specified in the return method but it's being accessed by all users.